# Is it possible to make text appear from the bottom with just HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build my first web page and I am only allowed to use HTML and CSS. I have a text inside a div and I want to make it appear from the bottom when the page opens. Is it possible to recreate this effect only using HTML and CSS?

Comment: Can you put some HTML code that you have tried to make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cant use javascript for stuff like this, try take a look at css keyframes.
They are used for looped animations and other stuff.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Answer (score 0):

If the animation must appear after the page fully loaded then, You must integrate JavaScript because you have to call onload event then run the animation. otherwise is not possible that is bcs the page maybe take too long to load on slow internet connect so the animation won't be consistence.

If you choose this approach. here is an example:

```
document.onreadystatechange = () =>{
  if ( document.readyState === 'complete' ) {
    // Add class animation to div element.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this one. You'll get an idea from this one I guess

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid skyblue;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.item .content {
  position: relative;
  top: 270px;   /* 270px top + 30px line height = 300px outer container height*/
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.item:hover .content{
  top: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"><span class="content">dummy text for test</span></div>
```